# TypeError: Labels in y_true and y_pred should be of the same type. Got y_true=['0' '1'] and y_pred=[0 1] in printing classification report

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I try to fit some ML algorithems (SVM, Randome Forst etc). Also, I fit a xgboost model, and I get the 10 most important features already.

But when I print the classification report by :

```
print(classification_report(y_test,y_predict))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Labels in y_true and y_pred should be of the same type. Got 
y_true=['0' '1'] and y_pred=[0 1]. Make sure that the predictions provided by 
the classifier coincides with the true labels.
```

my:

```
x_train.shape = (88, 229049)
y_train.shape = (88,)
x_test.shape = (22, 229049)
y_test.shape = (22,)
```

Why am I getting the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your predictions and your outputs are of a different dtype, char and numeric - you can change the type of your numpy array like this:

```
y_true = y_true.astype(y_pred.dtype)
```